# Could you recommend a simple script or software for tracking movements of white dots on a dark background?

Tags: images, image-processing, bash, tracking, unix

There are a set of black-white images of moving objects. Every image is a simple frame obtained from video file and then binarised using special algorithm. Moved objects are shown in white and the background is pure black. Each frame is a 1-bit tiff image.

[image]

I need to track all objects on the series of frames and obtain path coordinates for every objects. I need to do this automatically on a server using bash script or something else that can automate this task.

ImageJ\Fiji have suck plugins but they cann't load 1 bit tiffs and it is difficult to automate them.

Could you recommend a software\script for auto tracking such objects?